# Do functions and variables outside the return method get re-created each re-render in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was curious if you could create a NEW function and object each, and re-render. Like, in order to just have one, do I need to put it outside the component entirely?

For example

```
const ReactComponentExample = () => {
    const exampleFnc = {
        return 'name';
    };

    const styles = { background: 'red' };

    return (

        <div style={styles}>
            <p>Hello</p>
            {exampleFnc()}
        </div>

    );
};
```

^ above, I create an fnc and an object outside of the return method.

Tried the above code snippet but I don't know enough about the web tools to dissect if what I think is actually happening ie; the fnc is new or not.

Comment: `return` is not a method. **All** the code in the function runs when the function is called. This has nothing to do with React.

Comment: "*Will it create a NEW function and object each re-render?*" - yes.  "*In order to just have one, do I need to put it outside the component entirely?*" - yes.

Answer (score 0):

Functions and variables declared inside a component are re-created every time the component is re-rendered. but those declared outside the component are not re-created on each render. This is because they are not part of the component's local state or prop.

```js
// example of a function and object created outside of the ReactComponentExample.

const exampleFnc = {
   return 'name';
};

const styles = { background: 'red' };

const ReactComponentExample = () => {

    return (

        <div style={styles}>
            <p>Hello</p>
            {exampleFnc()}
        </div>

    );
};
```